# Add css to format table into grid

Tags: javascript, css, html

So in my php file, the groups are listed from top-bottom. I want to list them from left-right, and then like start the next row, so they are all in a grid format displayed nicely across the page. How can i add html/css to do this?[image: this is what I have right now]

```
Object.keys(cats).forEach(function(Group) {
      let html = '';

      // Append the 'category' header

      html = '<tr>';
      html += '<td><h1>'+"Group"+ Group+'</h1></td>';
      html += '</tr>';
      $('table').append(html);


      // Loop through the results for this 'category'
      cats[Group].forEach(function(element) {

        var names = element.names;

        var img = "<img src=' " + randomImage+ " ' />";

        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><p>' + names + '</p></td> ';

        html += '<td><p>' + img + '</p></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);

      });

    });

    });

    </script>

    </body>

    <table> </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you use display: flex or css grids instead of using a table?

Comment: May I recommend [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) as a separation of HTML and Javascript?

Comment: @encrypt in regards the question you deleted, you could use `base64_encode` inside your while for the photo and then on your javascript code that uses the photo use `data:image/png;base64` to display it.

Comment: @prix Hey can you expand on this please? So I think that the $table can't just store "photo"=> $photo, so how do I insert it into the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was suggesting in my comments you could create a table for each group (in your for loop) and append them to a div with id='tables_container'.

Then in CSS set the width of the tables to be 33% and float them left as follows:

## CSS

```
table{
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

## JavaScript/JQuery

```
Object.keys(cats).forEach(function(Group) {
      let html = '';

      //add the table opening tag to the html variable
      html += '<table>';
      //Append the 'category' header
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td><h1>'+"Group"+ Group+'</h1></td>';
      html += '</tr>';

      // Loop through the results for this 'category'
      cats[Group].forEach(function(element) {   
        var names = element.names;
        var img = "<img src=' " + randomImage+ " ' />";
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><p>' + names + '</p></td> ';
        html += '<td><p>' + img + '</p></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
      });
      //add the table closing tag to the html variable
      html += '</table>'; 
      //now that our html variable contains the table html for this group we append it to the tables_container
      $('#tables_container').append(html);
});
```

## HTML

Instead of having `<table>` in your html document you would have a container for the tables.

```
<div id="tables_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to tweek this - I used an [example from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_column_cards.asp). It will give you 3 columns wrapped together into one row. The columns will collapse into one with the items stacked on top of eachother if the screen is too small for all three columns. (run the snippet and see it in action) I set this up with cards, which you could eliminate (should you choose to do so). Adjust it as neccessary, then set up the corresponding html elements in your javascript. Hope this helps!

```css
<style>
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    }
 
 .row { margin: 0 10px; }
 
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    }
    
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    }
    
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
}        
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Column Cards</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div class="row"><!-- stretches across page -->
    <div class="column"> <!-- 1 of 3 -->
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Group 1</h1>
            <p><img src =""> name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column"> <!-- 2 of 3 -->
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Group 2</h1>
            <p><img src =""> name</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="column"> <!-- 3 of 3 -->
        <div class="card">
            <h1>Group 3</h1>
            <p><img src =""> name</p>
        </div>
    </div>    

</div> <!-- end of row -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your heading column in the first row should span to 2 to match the second row.
Is this what you are looking? Run the snippet.

```css
table tr > *{
  display: block;
}
table tr {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h1>Group 1</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>Name 1</p></td>
    <td><p>IMG</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, so bascially, I like the format I have right now, it's just that I want the different groups to be beside each other, left to right, insted of top to bottom. so like 3 of them on the first row. then 3 below those 3, etc. Because I might have over 10 groups and scrolling vertical is annoying

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>
        Group1
      </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h3>
        Group2
      </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so I like the image and text format you did, but agian, I need the group1 and group2, to be BESIDE each other left-right. So the exact same thing you did here but 3 groups should be in the same row. SO imagine a 3x3 grid if i had 9 groups

Comment: Since the data is dynamic it would be a little harder to maintain something that you are looking for.

Comment: it's just being pulled from the DB, can't i just re-arrange the tr or td or add some css? like my goal is to just have the groups being displayed on the whole page Right now they are just top-bottom on the left side, the whole right side of the page is empty

Comment: @encrypt i have two ideas. 1. you could create a table for each group and append them to a div with id='table_wrapper'. Then in css set the width of the tables to be 33% and float them left. Css code: float: left; .. you'd need to put css on the table_wrapper to be overflow:hidden; so that the floats are rendered... my other idea is more complicated and it involves giving a unique id to each table row.  I will have to get back to you tomorrow with that one as its 4.a.m here. Lol

Comment: Yeah so I tried creating a table for each group but I'm unable to figure out how to seperate the groups in my code above. In my code above, each element is a <tr> so the Group1 is a tr, the name+image is another tr, and its just a huge list of TR. I want to create blocks for each group so I need to seperatre the different groups. How can I do that in my for loops so far. Btw cats is an object, so it would have like array[0] : 0: group#:1, name=firstname1, etc . 
array[0]: 1 : group#1, firstname2, etc

Comment: @encypt i understand. Can you post the object in your code so i can see it properly. Or a sample of it.

Comment: @encrypt I posted some code to show you how you would do this in your for loop. Hope this helps.